# Understanding adding to Front of a Linked List

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

Let's say I have a list like such:

```
[1]-> [2]-> [3]-> [4]-> [5]->NULL
```

Where the value of 1 is the head, and 5 is the tail.
I'm following the example code shown here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29784/reversing-a-linked-list-and-adding-removing-nodes

What I don't understand is this line (In the addtoFront function)

```
ptr->value = input;
ptr->next = head;  // Point next value to the previous head
head = ptr;
```

Here's what I get.
    `ptr->value = input`

this line initializes the node called pointer with the given value

```
`ptr->next = head;`
```

this line sets the next pointer of the new item (To be inserted at the front), to the previous head, so we have something like this:

Insert [9] to front, so:

```
[9] (new head points to old head)
[9] -> [1] (9's next pointer points to 1)
```

What I don't get is this line:

```
head = ptr;
```

Reading this confuses me in the sense that I'm interpreting it as setting the two nodes equal to each other, i.e [1] becomes [9] so we have 2 nodes that are [9], `[9]->[9]->[2]->[3]->[4]->[5]->NULL`

but that's clearly not the case.

Once theirs no Arrow notation `->`, I seem to get lost in what's going on exactly (For most of the functions present). Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `head` always points to first node, so when you insert a new first node you have to make head point to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are thinking of pointers in terms of concrete instances rather than as actual pointers to memory locations.

In the question you referenced, head is a pointer to a memory location which contains a node instance.

The code:
    head = ptr

is updating the memory location to which head points, while the original location of head is now contained within ptr->next.

To get the actual node value of head, you need to dereference the pointer:

```
*head
```

So for example, given a linked list head pointing to memory location 8, which contains a node instance with value 'a', and a new input 'b':

Before executing the code you point to:

1. head == 8
2. head->value == 'a'
3. head->next = NULL;
4. ptr == 12 // This is an arbitrary memory location picked by me to be returned from the call to malloc
5. ptr->value == 'b'
6. ptr->next = NULL;

Once the code block you highlight is executed:

1. head == 12
2. head->value == 'b'
3. head->next = 8;
4. head->next->value == 'a'
5. head->next->next == NULL;
6. ptr == 12
7. ptr->value == 'b'
8. ptr->next = NULL;

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a linked list like so:

```
 H         T
[3]->[2]->[1]->NULL
```

And we want to insert a node with element `4` to the front (head side). First we need to create a new node off to the side, pointed to by `ptr`:

```
ptr      H         T
[4]     [3]->[2]->[1]->NULL
```

Then we need to link it to the head of the list:

```
ptr->next = head

ptr      H         T
[4]---->[3]->[2]->[1]->NULL
```

Last but not least, we need to update the head pointer to point to the new beginning of the list since now it would be pointing to the second element in the list instead of the first. `ptr` is now pointing to the new first element of the list.

```
head = ptr;

ptr
 H              T
[4]->[3]->[2]->[1]->NULL
```

And presto, the insertion is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the detail:

Your pointers look like this:

head -> next -> next -> next -> tail

```
ptr->value = input;
```

Now it looks like this:

head -> next -> next -> next -> tail -> null

and

ptr -> null

So you have basically two lists at this point.

```
ptr->next = head;  // Point next value to the previous head
```

Now you're attaching your two lists:

ptr -> head -> next -> next -> next -> tail -> null

```
head = ptr;
```

And now you're making sure what you call `head` points to that new block instead of the old one.

head (formerly ptr) -> next (formerly head) -> next -> next -> next -> tail -> null

And now you have inserted that new value to the front of your list.